# Smallest possible hash that limits collision

Tags: hash, collision

We have several collections of between 1 and 500 elements. The average collection size is 17. 
We want to have hashes of all the elements to make sure a new element is not yet part of the collection, and we're looking for the smallest possible hash string. We currently use a `sha1` of one of the unique element to each item in a collection, but we'd like to reduce the size of it.

What are the ways we could use to shorten the string we have to store: take X first elements in the string? X last?

Is it safe to take just a small subset of the sha1 string? If so, what is the collision probability with say X characters and 500 elements? (with X being equal to 3,4,5 or more?)